# InfiniteWP installation fails - CONFIGURABLE MAX EXECUTION TIME DISABLED

Tags: installation

I have setup a lampp stack on ubuntu, and I can install wordpress, but when I want to install InfiniteWP, I get this error:

> "CONFIGURABLE MAX EXECUTION TIME. The max execution time should be configurable = DISABLED"

and it should say ENABLED, so I can't finish the installation. I have tested the InfiniteWP installation on a local wamp server, on my windows pc and it work's okay, what's missing or how do I fix this error ?

Comment: set_time_limit() function could be disabled by your hosting provider in your server !. This function used in Infinitewp to reduce time out problems. So contact your hosting provider to enable set_time_limit() function.

Comment: This sounds like a server configuration question. Are you asking how to reconfigure your server or bypass an annoying imposed limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the restriction just by manually changing the URL in your browser.

The button to access to the next step is just disabled. If you inspect the html code of the button, you can see this is a normal link.

So you can just copy the link to access to the next step: replace `?step=checkRequirement` by `?step=enterDetails` in your browser address bar.

I just did it and was able to complete the installation. InfiniteWP is working properly.

(I am on a shared hosting and I am not able to change the configuration value)